# Dimension of mass of black hole in natural unit

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, black-holes, mass, dimensional-analysis

I am reading articles on superradiance, specifically, massive scalr field in Kerr geometry. https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.22.2323

One assumption of the article is $$\mu M\ll1,$$ where $\mu$ is the mass of the scalar field, and $M$ is the mass of the black hole.
I wonder how can their product be much smaller than one, which is dimesionless, since both of them have the dimension of mass?

Comment: For the mass of blackhole, its dimensions is taken as the dimensions of the length, e.g. Schwarzschild radius.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files.

Answer (score 0):

When quantum field theory is applied to black holes, we work in Planck units (or slight variants, e.g. we might use $16\pi G=1$ instead of $G=1$, but that doesn't really matter in $\ll$ conditions). Therefore, the condition is $\mu M\ll M_\text{Pl}^2=c\hbar/G$.